# Blocking port 53 on router

Tags: networking, router, dns, firewall, opendns

I'm trying to block port 53 on my ZTE H298A router.

I've already set up an `allow` rule which includes OpenDNS' DNS... but I keep getting an error when trying to set up a `discard` rule to block port 53 (as per OpenDNS' recommendations).

> Current operation is invalid, please check whether Destination IP
> Range is legal.

Am I doing something wrong? or might my ISP / router prohibit me from changing it? My ISP (Hyperoptic) are refusing to help me with it.

Router settings :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The destination IP range looks correct. If it's not accepted, that's a firmware bug in your router.

Try reducing it to `255.255.255.254` in case the router doesn't like the "broadcast" address being included in the range for some weird reason.

If that doesn't help, try reducing it further to `239.255.255.255` or even to `223.255.255.255` and see if that works. (Addresses 224.x to 239.x are for multicast groups, not hosts, while addresses 240.x to 255.x are just reserved due to a historical mistake, so neither of them will be seen on the Internet anytime soon.)

Similarly it's possible that the router doesn't like 0.0.0.0 as the "start" address – try increasing it to `0.0.0.1` or even to `1.0.0.0` as 0.x is also unusable in any case. Functionally the entire Internet is 1.0.0.0–223.255.255.255.

(In the very unlikely case that the router dislikes the inclusion of "localhost" addresses in the middle you can split it into two rules, one for 1.0.0.0–126.255.255.255 and another for 128.0.0.0–. I'm very much only guessing at this point)

Also, the **source** IP range probably should not be all-zero, but should cover all possible IP addresses exactly like your destination range does. It's possible that this is the actual problem but the error message is wrong.

Comment: Thank you! I tried a few of those and managed to set it as '1.0.0.0 ~ 239.255.255.255' — which the router will accept but it still seems possible to override OpenDNS on my phone by changing to Googles' DNS... any ideas why this might be?

Comment: My guess is that your phone starts using DNS over TLS on port 853 instead. (It might even support DNS over HTTPS, on the common port 443, which is going to be _difficult_ to block.)

Comment: I see! Thanks for clarifying... I've marked your answer as correct anyway as it did still answer the question I was asking at the time :)